# Angular test Class with service dependency

Tags: angular, testing, dependency-injection, karma-jasmine

I'm trying to test a plain `class` (not a component) in Angular which has a service dependency and a separate constructor argument. I've mirrored [the docs](https://angular.io/guide/testing-components-scenarios#component-with-a-dependency) for component testing with a dependency, but I get the following error:

`Unexpected value 'MyClass' imported by the module 'DynamicTestModule'. Please add a @NgModule annotation.`

`my-service.service.ts`:

```
@Injectable({
    providedIn: 'root',
})
export class MyService { ... }
```

`my-class.ts`:

```
import { inject } from '@angular/core';
import { MyService } from './my-service.service';

export class MyClass {
    private _myService: MyService = inject(MyService);
    private _name: string;

    constructor(name: string) {
        this._name = name;
    }
}
```

`my-class.spec.ts`

```
import { ComponentFixture, TestBed } from '@angular/core/testing';
import { MyService } from './my-service.service';
import { MyClass } from './my-class';

describe('MyClass', () => {
    let myClass: MyClass;
    let mockMyService: Partial<MyService>;
    let fixture: ComponentFixture<MyClass>;

    beforeEach(() => {
        mockMyService = {};

        TestBed.configureTestingModule({
            imports: [MyClass],
            providers: [{ provide: MyService, useValue: mockMyService }],
        });

        fixture = TestBed.createComponent(MyClass); // causes error
        myClass = fixture.componentInstance;

        TestBed.inject(MyService);
    });

    it('should create', () => {
        expect(myClass).toBeTruthy();
    });
});
```

updated `my-class.spec.ts`

```
import { MyClass } from './my-class';

describe('MyClass', () => {
    let myClass: MyClass;

    beforeEach(() => {
        myClass = new MyClass('someName');
    });

    it('should create', () => {
        expect(myClass).toBeTruthy();
    });
});
```

How can I test this plain class with the service dependency?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are using `MyClass` as a component, you need the `@Component` decorator to initialize it as a component so we can create a dummy class with the component decorator and inherit all the contents of `MyClass` into the testing class `MyClassMocked`

Since you are using `MyClass` in the imports array, that means, it must be `standalone: true` so I have added that, if you do not want `standalone as true` then you need to add `MyClass` to the `declarations` array instead!

Also we need to update the class `MyClass` to `MyClassMocked` wherever its used as a type!

```
import { ComponentFixture, TestBed } from '@angular/core/testing';
import { MyService } from './my-service.service';
import { MyClass } from './my-class';

import { inject, Component } from '@angular/core';
import { MyService } from './my-service.service';

@Component({ selector: 'my-class', standalone: true, template: '' })    
export class MyClassMocked extends MyClass {
     constructor() { super(); }
}

describe('MyClass', () => {
    let myClass: MyClassMocked;
    let mockMyService: Partial<MyService>;
    let fixture: ComponentFixture<MyClassMocked>;

    beforeEach(() => {
        mockMyService = {};

        TestBed.configureTestingModule({
            imports: [MyClassMocked],
            providers: [{ provide: MyService, useValue: mockMyService }],
        });

        fixture = TestBed.createComponent(MyClassMocked); // should work!
        myClass = fixture.componentInstance;

        TestBed.inject(MyService);
    });

    it('should create', () => {
        expect(myClass).toBeTruthy();
    });
});
```

Comment: @user9506231 please check this updated answer!

Comment: I understand that because `MyClass` isn't a component, I can't treat it as a component in the testing. I tried your proposed solution of creating a new `MyClassMocked` and that worked. But is there a way to test the `MyClass` without creating a new component in the test file? Ideally by just doing `myClass = new MyClass('someName')`? The problem with using `new` is the dependency injection needs to be set up for the class creation. Is that possible?

Comment: I've added an updated test file showing the desired testing functionality, by just using `new`, but this now gets the error: `NG0203: inject() must be called from an injection context such as a constructor, a factory function, a field initializer, or a function used with runInInjectionContext`.

Comment: @user9506231 inject is supposed to be used in an angular context like `component`, `service`, `directive`, etc, its not possible to test it without that! when you are using `TestBed`, you can also use plain jasmine testing, but that looks like a separate question entirely!